# SWinTypeLibs Package from Omegahat

Tags: r

I have Googled for this R package, SWinTypeLibs, but all the hyperlinks are broken.
I'd appreciate any help in locating this package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.omegahat.org/SWinTypeLibs/

This seems to be a working link for the full windows offerings at Omegahat:

http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/

Answer (score 0):

the package was migrated to github, you need to get it from here  https://github.com/omegahat/SWinTypeLibs

```
devtools::install_github("omegahat/SWinTypeLibs")
```